# Check if sql statement has been excuted

Tags: sql, stored-procedures

How to check if sql statement has been executing before executing another SQL statement.

I make like this

```
 DECLARE tempId double default 2;
 insert IGNORE  into  `system_users`( `user_id`,`username`,`password`) values (id , userName ,md5(password)) ;

  set tempId= last_insert_id();

  IF tempId <> 0 THEN     
        insert into  `user_profile`(`user_id`, `full_name`, `cellphone`, `Date_time_ added`,`added_by`) values (id, fullName ,cellPhone , CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(),addedBy ) ;
```

function last_insert_id() doesn't work with my case because user_id is not auto increment pk, it's the identification number fot the user. what is the function that is used to test execution of sql statement.

Comment: Does your DBMS allow you to use transactions?

Comment: Mmm what do you mean with transactions?

Comment: I am referring to [Database transactions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_transaction).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't specify what DMBS you're using so I'll assume MySQL (it looks like MySQL to me, please specify if otherwise) For `INSERT` statements, use [ROW_COUNT()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#function_row-count)

E.g.

```
DECLARE tempId double default 2;
 insert IGNORE  into  `system_users`( `user_id`,`username`,`password`) values (id , userName ,md5(password)) ;

set tempId= ROW_COUNT();
```

This will return the number of affected rows.

Also, note that for `SELECT` statements, you would use [FOUND_ROWS()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#function_found-rows)

e.g.

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS * FROM MyTable; 
SELECT FOUND_ROWS();
```

Although this will tell you the total number of rows found, regardless of whether or not you have a `LIMIT` clause.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe something like this. See if the inserted row already exists:

```
 insert IGNORE  into  `system_users`( `user_id`,`username`,`password`) values (id , userName ,md5(password)) ;

  IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT NULL FROM system_users WHERE system_users=id) 
  BEGIN     
        insert into  `user_profile`(`user_id`, `full_name`, `cellphone`, `Date_time_ added`,`added_by`) values (id, fullName ,cellPhone , CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(),addedBy ) ;
  END
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add this before the end of the stored procedure, it will indicate if any records have been affected.

```
    IF @@ROWCOUNT <>1
    BEGIN
    RAISERROR ('An error occured',10,1)
    RETURN -1
    END
```

For exmaple

```
    DECLARE tempId double default 2;
     insert IGNORE  into  `system_users`( `user_id`,`username`,`password`) values (id , userName ,md5(password)) ;

    IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT NULL FROM system_users WHERE system_users=id) 
    BEGIN     
    insert into  `user_profile`(`user_id`, `full_name`, `cellphone`, `Date_time_ added`,`added_by`) values (id, fullName ,cellPhone , CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(),addedBy ) ;

    IF @@ROWCOUNT <>1
    BEGIN
    RAISERROR ('No rows were affected',10,1)
    RETURN -1
    END
    END
```

Thus, the RAISERROR variable will contain 'No rows were affected' if there were no rows modified.  Is this what you were looking for, or am I misunderstanding...

Answer (score 0):

You have to test the value of SQLCODE

> The most important and widely used field of the SQLCA data structure is the SQLCODE variable. Each time Microsoft® SQL Server™ 2000 runs an Embedded SQL statement, it sets the value of the SQLCODE variable to indicate whether the last Embedded SQL statement completed successfully. A value of 0 indicates that the last Embedded SQL statement was successful. Values other than 0 indicate warnings or errors.

source http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa225200(v=sql.80).aspx

List of differents SQLCODE values : http://www.caliberdt.com/tips/sqlcode.htm

( I took MSSQL Server but SQLCODE is standard that is available in every SQL engines)